# SharePoint list template migration error

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

**Goal:**  Move SharePoint list from old site collection to new site collection.

**Approach:**

1. I save the SharePoint list as a template (.stp),
2. Then move .stp file to the new site collection list template gallery
3. Create custom SharePoint list using my newly created template
4. The SharePoint list populates perfectly.

**Problem:** when I try to edit or add items to the SharePoint list, I’m taken to the default SharePoint page “An unexpected error has occurred”

Answer (score 1):

Open you web.config file of the SharePoint web Application, search for **CallStack** change it to **true** and seach for **CustomError** and set its value to **Off**. Do the action again you will get to know the actual error causing the error. Rectify it or post the error that will help to point out the issue.

Also notes in case of STP,

1. If have some LookUp field in the List template, you will need to recreate those fields again or Follow the workaround as described in [article](http://www.heathersolomon.com/blog/archive/2005/11/11/2973.aspx)
2. If you have created any Site Column make sure that is there in the new site collection as well.